# Customizing a QDockWidget in Qt without QtDesigner

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, customizing, qdockwidget

(sry for my bad english but i'll give my best)

I currently try to customize the style of several QDockWidgets. The only solution i found via the [Qt Documentation -> Style Sheet](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/stylesheet-examples.html) is setting a Stylesheet to the Object in the QtDesignerView by right MouseClick -> set Stylesheet and kinda hardcode (looking similar to css). 
Pityfully i do not use the QtDesigner but code the graphical stuff in the EditorView of QtCreator.

My Question now - is it possible to customize Widgets by normal Editor nicer than

```
widget.setObjectName("widget")
```

and then setting the stylesheet via the constructor like this:

`this->setStyleSheet("QDockWidget#widget{ background-color: red;........}");`

this works fine for brief PushButtons e.g. but putting together dozen lines as a String could not be the best solution could it?
I would be glad about some hints because i cannot find much about that on the net, my cpp/Qt knownledge is not yet the best though :(

thanks

Comment: Your best would be to come back to the question and reply to the people trying to help you.  This is heading towards Spam.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best solution but I'd probably do something along these lines:

- Create the desired stylesheet in a .css file
- Subclass `QDockWidget`
- Add methods that use `QFile` to load/parse the .css file and set the styles etc
- Then I might get fancy and do some things with `QStyle` and other related classes

Answer (score 0):

you call setStyleSheet from your program.

example:

```
pb->setStyleSheet(QApplication::translate("failoverCrit", "color: rgb(0, 0, 0);background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.922018, y1:0.574, x2:0.385321, y2:0.159, stop:0 rgba(106, 106, 106, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
```

example2:

```
ui.pbAssign->setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8("QPushButton {\n"
     "    border: 1px solid green;"
     "    border-radius: 3px;"
     "    padding: 4px;"
     "    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:1, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgb(255,255,153), stop:0.668182 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));"
     " }\n"
     ""));
```

to remove the styling:

```
ui.pbAssign->setStyleSheet("");
```

Comment: actually i did not read your question through before giving an answer but I wonder why you cant use Designer.  Possibly you could generate the stylesheet in  qtDesigner then view the form source and finally copy and paste the generated stylesheet.